# jQuery Dialog, closing when click outside

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I know I can use the following to close the dialog box by clicking outside:

```
$('.ui-widget-overlay').click(function() { $("#dialog").dialog("close"); });
```

But how do I change this so it works for every dialog box, ie I want to say close any dialog box as we have multiple on a page and would be easier to have one line of code?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is overkill, but try

```
$('.ui-widget-overlay').live('click',
    function() {
        $(".ui-dialog").dialog("close");
    }
);
```

You only need to run this code once on your page, the `live` method should make it work any time you open a dialog.

EDIT: If this isn't working, it might be `.dialog`'s fault. Try

```
$('.ui-widget-overlay').live('click',
    function() {
        $(".ui-dialog").each(
            function() {
               $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this however it doesnt seem to work. via Chrome Dev Tools, I can see the dialog box does have a class of ui-dialog so unsure why this isnt working.

It works when I specify the ID.

Comment: OK, so could you try the second example?

Answer (score 1):

you can give each dialog a class

and then select it and run on each and cose it even if its not open it will work:

```
$('.ui-widget-overlay').click(function() { $(".dialogs").each(function()
 {$(this).dialog("close");}) });
```

Comment: The UI code already gives every dialog the class `ui-dialog`, as described on http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

The answers given almost work.  Except you can't call the `dialog('close')` on elements with the `ui-dialog` class.  That is the jquery-ui generated content around your original element and the close must be called on the original element you used when you called `.dialog`.  Fortunately jquery adds a `ui-dialog-content` class to them.  Use that to modify Guy's solution and you get:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-widget-overlay', function() {
    $('.ui-dialog-content').each(function() {
       $(this).dialog('close'); 
    });
});​
```

You can try it out for yourself over on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/admsteck/RXJAs/).

EDIT: Changed `.click` to `.live` since the `ui-widget-overlay` may not exist yet when this code is executed.

EDIT: Changed to `.on` instead of `.live` since it is depreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From my tests, this is working well.

```
$('[data-role=dialog]').dialog( "close" );
```

It closes any dialog.